# Automotive grade linux (AGL) 3.0(Charming chinook) on freescale SABRE for Automotive Infotainment based on the i.MX 6 Series

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto

I have freescale SABRE for Automotive Infotainment based on the i.MX 6 Series board AGL recently released its AGL 3.0 version which is supported only freescale sabre lite board as per below link.
https://wiki.automotivelinux.org/agl-distro#supported_hardware

I tried this tutorial but the build failed:http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/AGLAMM_How%20we%20Run%20AGL%20on%20i.MX%20processors_tkobayashi_25FEB16%20rev.D.pdf

Is there any other ways that I can build AGL 3.0 for SABRE for Automotive Infotainment board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move below folder

   > $cd ./AGL3.0/meta-agl/templates/machine
2. Copy 'imx6qsabrelite' folder

   > $cp -r imx6qsabrelite imx6qsabreauto
3. Move 'imx6qsabreauto' folder

   > $cd imx6qsabreauto
4. Modify 50_local.conf.inc file

   > [Origin file contents]
   > MACHINE = 'imx6qsabrelite'
   >
   > [Change file contents]
   > MACHINE = 'imx6qsabreauto'
5. Building the AGL distro

   > $source ../../../../meta-agl/scripts/aglsetup.sh -b build-imx6qsabreauto -m imx6qsabreauto agl-demo agl-netboot agl-appfw-smack
   > $bitbake agl-demo-platform

I think...Above steps are a solution for you.

If you have another questions, contact me.

Thanks.

Comment: @Soon-yeon                                                                                                 I made all changes told by you. After running bitbake commmand the build was successful but when i see /build/tmp/deploy/images  are of again for sabrelite only

Comment: @Veer_m_k Did you modify 50_local.conf.inc file? This is file I uesd. [file link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_kwM12hsTcyeS1SVEZyY2RVNGc)

Comment: @Soon-yeon yes I have modified it and it's identical to your file.

Comment: @Veer_m_k You used wrong build directory. If you run this command($source ../../../../meta-agl/scripts/aglsetup.sh -b build-imx6qsabreauto -m imx6qsabreauto agl-demo agl-netboot agl-appfw-smack), it was changed build diretory. The correct build directory is /build-imx6qsabreauto

Comment: @Veer_m_k '-b' option means build directory name.

Comment: @Veer_m_k Please check [./AGL3.0/build-imx6qsabreauto/tme/deploy/images]

Comment: @Soon-yeon Thanks it worked :) i flashed the images on board also

Comment: @Veer_m_k That's okay.